# How to convert currency format label to double for calculation purpose

Tags: c#, visual-studio, currency

I have a label **(lblAmountTendered)** which contains Currency String in it. I would like to convert it into double to perform some calculation. However, it shown an **Error Message: Input string was not in a correct format** in the first statement.

Here is my code:

```
double balance = double.Parse(amount) - double.Parse(lblAmountTendered.Text.ToString());
lblBalanceDue.Text = balance.ToString("c2",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-MY"));
```

For Example:

lblAmountTendered = RM 15
I want to retrieve the value of it (15) for calculation.

Looking forward for the solution. I appreciate for your help! :)

> ***PROBLEM SOLVED***
>   lblAmountTendered.Text.ToString().**Remove(0,3)**
>
> **Remove(0,3)** helps us to remove 'RM' from 'RM 15', so we can convert it to double or float easily as shown in below:
>
> **float.Parse**(lblAmountTendered.Text.ToString().**Remove(0, 3)**)

Comment: You need to give us the value that you are trying to parse.

Comment: changing this line would help? 

`double.Parse(amount.ToString()) - double.Parse(lblAmountTendered.Text.ToString());`

Comment: @RahulHendawe Sorry, it still getting the same error :(

Comment: Why are you trying to parse the *label* text instead of simply reading the *value* that was used to generate that text?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, you're right, that's the easiest way to do! I'm just wondering is there any alternative way for it. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: It's not the easiest, it's the only one that makes sense. *Why* try to parse some label to get to a value you should already have? Isn't that total value stored in a field or property?

Answer (score 0):

Here you first need to retrieve the numeric value from a string using below regex:

```
string resultNum = Regex.Match(lblAmountTendered.Text, @"\d+").Value;
```

and then use `resultNum` in your code like-

```
double balance = double.Parse(amount.ToString()) - double.Parse(resultNum);
lblBalanceDue.Text = balance.ToString("c2",CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-MY"));
```

Comment: op has mentioned `RM 15` this may be the value he has and the given regex will work for this.

Comment: Consider a universal approach rather than specific to the example. The majority of currency won't be an integer, and the OP isn't going to list an example for each currency that exists.